# Trying to sample iteratively, while providing access to all previously sampled steps

Tags: python, time-series, sampling

I'm trying to change the TimeSynth package to my specific needs. This package creates a timeseries and adds red/white noise to it. However, I already have another package which I use to create specific timeseries and I would like to use the TimeSynth package to add red noise to my timeseries.

In 'timeseries.py' the following code is present:

```
    for i in range(n_samples):
        # Get time
        t = time_vector[i]
        # Sample error
        if not self.noise_generator is None:
            errors[i] = self.noise_generator.sample_next(t, samples[:i - 1], errors[:i - 1])

        # Sample signal
        signal = self.signal_generator.sample_next(t, samples[:i - 1], errors[:i - 1])
        signals[i] = signal

        # Compound signal and noise
        samples[i] = signals[i] + errors[i]
```

The problem is "sample_next" cannot be used on my timeseries as it is specific to the timeseries created in this package "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample_next'". The following code is used to create the timeseries with the noise:

```
timeseries = ts.TimeSeries(demand, noise_generator=red_noise)
```

I was wondering how I could change the sampling of the signal in such a way that it would be able to sample my own timeseries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The problem is "sample.next" ` did you mean `sample_next` ?? What is `ts.TimeSeries`? specifically, what is `ts`?

Comment: Oh sorry yes I meant sample_next, my bad. Ts is "import timesynth as ts". As such, ts.TimeSeries refers to the TimeSeries function used in that package